# Storing file processing stages in Bash

Tags: bash

I'm writing a fairly length command which transforms text in a file:

```
grep -o '^[^#]*' file.txt | grep ':' | cut -d ':' -f1 | uniq | gcut -d '/' -f1,3 --output-delimiter=$'\t'
```

I would like to convert this into shell script. While this script runs correctly as a single series of pipes, I've having trouble breaking it up and doing the transformations one at a time.

I originally tried setting variables at each stage like:

```
CONTENT=$(grep -o '^[^#]*' $1)
SEGMENTS=$($CONTENT | grep ':')
```

but kept getting:

> command too long:

---

I also broke it up into sub shells (I think that's what they're called):

```
CONTENT=(grep -o '^[^#]*' $1)
```

And I can see that `echo $CONTENT` will print the command, not the text, so I thought I could:

```
SEGMENTS=($CONTENT | grep ':')
```

> parse error near `|'

---

I also tried:

```
CONTENT=$(grep -o '^[^#]*' $1)
SEGMENTS=(cat <($CONTENT) | grep ':')
```

But that didn't seem to work either.

How can I break up a really long string of text transformations in a more readable form? Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You want `content=$(grep -o '^[^#]*' "$1"); segments=$(echo "$content" | grep ':')`. Or just `segments=$(grep -o '^[^#]*' "$1"| grep ':')`. `$CONTENT | grep ':'` would try to execute the value of `$CONTENT` as a command. In the future, `set -x` and http://www.shellcheck.net are your friends.

Comment: Brillant. That works, thank you!

Comment: BTW, your multi-stage version is actually slower to run and less efficient. A shell pipeline runs all at once, rather than letting the first phase complete before starting the next.

Comment: Also, re variables -- all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the shell and operating system -- see relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html, paragraph 4; thus, your own scripts should use lower-case names to avoid unintentionally overwriting a variable with meaning to the system (as a shell variable whose name overlaps with an environment variable will implicitly update the latter).

Comment: I'm old-school, so if I wanted to break a long pipeline up in stages, I'd use files, not variables, to hold the intermediate results.  Be cautious about how you choose the intermediate file names (`mktemp` is a good command to know and use).  And add trap handling to remove intermediate files if the script is interrupted or otherwise signalled — you don't need the debris left behind, in general.  At least, you don't once the script is debugged.  You might want to provide a mechanism that _will_ leave the intermediate files alone when you're debugging.

Comment: Even when debugging, though, one can just add in the odd `tee` here and there to inspect pipeline contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A literal answer might look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#      ^^^^- needed for herestrings (the <<< syntax)

content=$(grep -o '^[^#]*' <file.txt)
segments=$(grep ':'        <<<"$content")
fields=$(cut -d ':' -f1    <<<"$segments")
uniq_fields=$(uniq         <<<"$fields")
result=$(gcut -d '/' -f1,3 --output-delimiter=$'\t')
```

Without bash, these stages might instead look like:

```
segments=$(printf '%s\n' "$content" | grep ':')
```

Don't do that, however: It's extremely inefficient, using far more memory than your original code and being unable to run in parallel (and thus taking longer to run if your input file is of any significant size).

---

If your goal is to allow inspection, consider something like the following:

```
grep -o '^[^#]*' file.txt | tee without_comments.txt \
  | grep ':'              | tee colons_only.txt \
  | cut -d ':' -f1        | tee fields_only.txt \
  | uniq                  | tee fields_uniq.txt \
  | gcut -d '/' -f1,3 --output-delimiter=$'\t'
```

...which will give you a separate output for each stage. Or, if you wanted code you wouldn't need to change between development and production mode, consider using a function:

```
set -o pipefail # prevent presence of a pipeline from changing exit status

logging() {
  filename=$1; shift
  if [ -n "$logdir" ]; then
    "$@" | tee -- "$logdir/$filename"
  else
    "$@"
  fi
}

logging     without_comments.txt grep -o '^[^#]*' file.txt \
  | logging colons_only.txt      grep ':' \
  | logging fields_only.txt      cut -d ':' -f1 \
  | logging fields_uniq.txt      uniq \
  | gcut -d '/' -f1,3 --output-delimiter $'\t'
```

...which would log only if the variable `logdir` is non-empty.

---

Given the job at hand, I would suggest using awk instead; the following will be *far* more efficient, and there's an argument to be made that it's more readable as well:

```
awk '
  BEGIN { IFS=":"; OFS="\t"; }    # split input on :s, combine output with tabs
  /#/ { gsub(/#.*/, "") }         # remove comments
  /:/ { seen[$1]++ }              # put field 1 of each line with a : into a map
  END {
    for (i in seen) {
      split($1, pieces, "/")      # split each map key on "/"s
      print pieces[0], pieces[2]  # and put the 1st and 3rd in output
    }
  }  
'
```

Answer (score 1):

If all you're looking for is readability, just add newlines:

```
grep -o '^[^#]*' file.txt |
grep ':' |
cut -d ':' -f1 |
uniq |
gcut -d '/' -f1,3 --output-delimiter=$'\t'
```

You can align the `|` symbols and add comments, too:

```
 grep -o '^[^#]*' file.txt | # Find the lines
 grep :                    | # use grep and cut instead
 cut -d : -f1              | # of awk for no particular reason
 uniq                      | # remove duplicates
 gcut -d '/' -f1,3 --output-delimiter=$'\t'
```